# react native: Ternary condition inside Text component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to make ternary condition so that if {title} contains part of text such as "appl" then 'styles.label' will be change to 'styles.label_2' .

```
const Field = ({ title, info }: Props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}> {title} </Text>
      <Text style={styles.info}>{info ? info : ''} </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that for sure.

The following checks if the `title` string contains `appl` and if so, use `styles.label2` otherwise, use `styles.label`

```
<Text style={title.includes('appl') ? styles.label2 : styles.label}> {title} </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a second style only to hide when it evaluates to false, I prefer evaluating before rendering the component -- therefore if it evaluates to false, no component is ever present, instead of a empty one:

```js
const Field = ({ title, info }: Props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}> {title} </Text>
      {info && info.contains("appl") && (<Text style={styles.info}>{info} </Text>)}
    </View>
  );
};
```